# Dynamic subdomain redirection

Tags: dns, zerigo

How do I redirect a dynamic subdomain to the same subdomain on a different domain?

```
*.example.com to *.example2.com
```

Can this be handled with Zerigo?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact requirements, you could achieve that with a [DNAME record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record#DNAME_record):

For example, you could have the following in your `example.com` zone file:

```
example.com.   IN   DNAME   example2.com.
```

and a pretty standard `example2.com` zone, you can mostly achieve the effect.

Querying `dig www.example.com`, you'd get:

```
example.com.      IN DNAME    exmaple2.com.
www.example.com.  IN CNAME    www.exmaple2.com.
```

However, if you had DNS records that you need directly under either zones, e.g. an `A`, `MX` or `TXT` record, they don't "alias" so you need to store them in both zones.

In any case, DNAME is not supported in most DNS providers (Zerigo included) that only gives you a web interface, so you'd need to run your own DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

In DNS you can not redirect, that is an HTTP function. But what you can do is use CNAMEs. A CNAME take a dns name and under the covers resolves it to another name. For example:

www.example.com resolves to www.example2.com. In the web browser the user will see www.example.com though.

What you will want to do is look into "wilcard CNAME". There is a limitation though. A wildcard CNAME will only point to a single address. This means that:

```
*.example.com will only ever point to a single address at example.com2 (let's say you pick bang.example2.com)

foo.example.com -> bang.example2.com
bar.example.com -> bang.example2.com
baz.example.com -> bang.example2.com
cux.example.com -> bang.example2.com
```

It is also important to note that not every DNS provider allows for wildcard CNAMEs. Also, not every DNS server allows wildcard CNAMEs. If you really want to have a wildcard CNAME point to the corresponding entry in example2.com, then you may want to look into powerDNS. It allows for 3rd party plugins written in various languages like lua. It also can be backed by a mysql, postgress, ldap, or a sqlite backed. This means that you can add that functionality yourself if it does not already exist.

Good luck